# Variable in For used for path in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, printing

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I am trying to gather a list of all printers on a machine, then have the script create a file for each printer and append the hostname to that file. I plan on having this run on each computer to allow us to know which computers will need to be in each print group for the new windows print server we are setting up.

The Code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
net use z: PATH TO SHARE HERE (this part works)
for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%1 in (`wmic printer get name`) do (
set str=''
echo %str%
set str=%%1
set str=!str:\==!
set str=!str: =!
echo !str!
echo "!str!.txt" >> test6.txt
hostname
hostname >> "!str!.txt"
)
```

The two lines of

```
set str=!str:\==!
set str=!str: =!
```

are to strip out the spaces, and to replace the \ at the begining of the 
printer name so it will be a valid file path. These seem to work as expected.

The output from the first run of the loop (the rest follow suit with the other printer names and have the same behavior)

ECHO is on.
WebExDocumentLoader
WW7L7NPWWZ1
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The echo on is for the echo of the empty !str! variable
The next line is the printer name in the variable
The output to the file test6.txt for that variable line   is: "WebExDocumentLoader.txt"
The hostname line outputs as expected.

The final line is driving me crazy because I can't figure out why "WebExDocumentLoader.txt" is giving an invalid syntax when it is supposed to be a filename.

I am totally at a loss as to why this won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

```dos
....
for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%1 in (`wmic printer get name`) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%%1") do set "str=%%a"
    ....
```

The output from `wmic` command includes an aditional carriage return character that is generating the error. The additional `for` will remove it before assigning the value to the variable.